# Disable 'find' command on Windows

Tags: windows-7, find

I've just downloaded some linux-tool emulators for windows (e.g. 'find', 'grep', etc.) as .exe files. I'd like to disable Windows' usual `find` command so that I can just type `find` into the command line, rather than the whole path to the linux-find executable. (Yes, I added the directory to my system's PATH variable, but Windows' find is still the default.)

Is there any way I can accomplish this, and if so, is there any danger of disrupting other activities? (e.g. Will Windows Explorer's search go wonky if it can't find `find` as usual?)

Specs: Windows 7

Comment: Probably belongs on superuser.

Answer (score 2):

Place your linux like `find` in the path before the windows `find`.

Comment: You can also just dump all of the commands in your sys32 folder and override all of the conflicts. :P

Comment: Queerly, I just made the change (moved the linux_tools dir to the start of the PATH variable), and now my find results are wrong: retaining the file path in my command returns excepted results, but using just `find` now returns 0 results (but gives no more complaint about parameter formatting). Help?

Comment: @Paul, when I try to remove commands from the sys32 folder, I'm stopped with the message that I need permission from TrustedInstaller. I'm already logged in as admin. Any idea what that's about?

Comment: apparently your admin doesn't have TrustedInstaller privileges.

Comment: but you shouldn't do what i was proposing. Paul Whelan's solution is the more correct one .

Comment: Strange Try running the where /? command and make sure the find command is your command

Comment: I ran `where /?` but don't know if I'm getting the expected output. Can you tell me? (pasted here: http://pastie.org/3342772 )